# When is %destructor invoked in BISON?

Tags: c++, bison

When is %destructor invoked in *BISON*? I have the following bison code:

```
%union{
    char * sval; 
    Variable * vval; 
} 

%token VARIABLE 
%token Literal 
%type <vval> Expression VARIABLE 
%type <sval> Literal 

%destructor { delete $$; } <vval> 
%destructor { delete $$; } Literal
```

where *Variable* is a class. I thought that after processing a line, all the *Variable* objects will be freed, but I can see no destructor invoked. And that will lead straightly to memory leak...

Edit: To be clear; I allocate a new *Variable* object for a new token, and this token is pushed to the BISON stack. I want to delete the *Variable* when it is popped by bison and discarded from the stack. I thought that %destructor serves that purpose, but I am not sure anymore..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out, that I should free() it after I perform the action, so for example

```
...
| String CONCAT String { $$ = concat($1,$3); free($1); free($3); }
...
```

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

[From the Bison Manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Destructor-Decl.html)

> Discarded symbols are the following:
>
> - stacked symbols popped during the first phase of error recovery,
> - incoming terminals during the second phase of error recovery,
> - the current lookahead and the entire stack (except the current
>     right-hand side symbols)  when the
>     parser returns immediately, and
> - the start symbol, when the parser succeeds.

So if you don't hit an error, the `%destructor` will be called on the stack if you return immediately ([call `YYABORT` or `YYACCEPT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Parser-Function.html)), or it will call it on start symbol if parsing succeeds.

Comment: Basically, the destructor gets called in all the places you can't easily clean up yourself in an action...